# How to Add Arrow to material UI popover Like ToolTip

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I would like to add Add an Arrow to the Popover as we have for the ToolTip

[image]   [image]

Is there any possibility to Add an Arrow ??

Answer (score 6):

According to the documentation, this snippet will do what you require
[image]

```
modifiers={[
    {
        name: 'arrow',
        enabled: true,
        options: {
            element: arrowRef,
        },
    },
]}
```

See scroll playground
https://mui.com/components/popper/

Comment: Can you enlighten me on arrowRef here and how do you set it?

Comment: The `arrowRef` is a reference to an element within the popover. `<Popover><span ref={setArrowRef} /></Popover>` for example. Note that `setArrowRef` is the setter for a `useState` call. Normally I would recommend using `useRef` but, for whatever reason, that does not work in this case and will throw console errors.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
import { Popover, type PopoverProps } from '@mui/material';

/**
 * The `Popover` that:
 * - is positioned at the bottom-right of the `anchorEl`, and
 * - has an arrow pointing to the `anchorEl`.
 */
export const PopoverWithArrow = (popoverProps: Omit<PopoverProps, 'anchorOrigin' | 'transformOrigin'>) => (
  <Popover
    anchorOrigin={{ horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'bottom' }}
    transformOrigin={{ horizontal: 'right', vertical: -5 }}
    slotProps={{
      paper: {
        sx: {
          overflow: 'visible',
          '&:before': {
            content: '""',
            display: 'block',
            position: 'absolute',
            top: 0,
            right: 8,
            width: 10,
            height: 10,
            backgroundColor: 'inherit',
            transform: 'translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg)',
            boxShadow: '-3px -3px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1)',
          },
        },
      },
    }}
    {...popoverProps}
  />
);
```

To use, simply give it an anchor:

```
<PopoverWithArrow anchorEl={anchorEl}>
  <h1>Your awesome Popover body content</h1>
</PopoverWithArrow>
```

[image: Popover with Arrow preview]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It is probably the cleanest solution that I found. I don't understand why MUI doesn't provide an easier arrow solution. The major point of using MUI is easy UI development.

This should be marked as accepted solution.

Answer (score 1):

MUI docs has an example with [arrow](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-popper/#scroll-playground). And the code of this example can be found in their [repo](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/4f2a07e140c954b478a6670c009c23a59ec3e2d4/docs/src/pages/components/popper/ScrollPlayground.js), which makes everything clear about the usage of modifiers and implementation of `arrowRef`